# How to reference specific field in this JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reference

trying to reference a field in this JSON but it's unlike anything in the examples I've been looking at so I'm kinda stumped.

**I want to know how to reference the field at the end "HOW DO I REFERENCE THIS?".** Thanks for any help.

```
var JSON = 
{ "employees": {
    "name" : "david",
    "car" : "audi"
     },
     {
     "name" : "jimmy",
     "car" : "VW"
     },

   "customers" : {
     "name" : "philip",
     "purchase": "cabbage"
     },
     {
     "name" : "Helen",
     "purchase": "HOW DO I REFERENCE THIS?"
     }
}


var x = "HOW DO I REFERENCE THIS?";
```

Comment: You don't, since you've coded up a syntax error :) What I'm saying is that your object literal is not valid. You can't have `{ }` blocks without property names.

Comment: Suggested reading: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object."](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) If valid, your snippet would be entirely JavaScript. Not JSON. They are certainly related, but not the same.

Answer (score 5):

With the right syntax, which I believe you want this:

```
var JSON = {
    "employees": [
    {
        "name": "david",
        "car": "audi"
    },
    {
        "name": "jimmy",
        "car": "VW"
    }],

    "customers": [
    {
        "name": "philip",
        "purchase": "cabbage"
    },
    {
        "name": "Helen",
        "purchase": "HOW DO I REFERENCE THIS?"
    }]
}
```

You can get `purchase` by using this:

```
for (var i in JSON.customers)
{
    var customer = JSON.customers[i];

    var value = customer.purchase; // cabbage, HOW DO I...
}
```

Comment: Yep you're all right, I read the freaking JSON wrong. It was very long. Square brackets are sneaky. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var JSON = {
    "employees": [{
        "name": "david",
            "car": "audi"
    }, {
        "name": "jimmy",
            "car": "VW"
    }],
        "customers": [{
        "name": "philip",
            "purchase": "cabbage"
    }, {
        "name": "Helen",
            "purchase": "HOW DO I REFERENCE THIS?"
    }]
}

$.each(JSON.customers, function (k, data) {
    alert(data.purchase);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/h39p5/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to find the purchase string for "Helen" or just the second customer, if it's the second customer it will be (with valid JSON):

```
var string = '{"employees": [{"name": "david", "car": "audi"}, {"name": "jimmy", "car": "VW"}], "customers": [{"name": "philip", "purchase": "cabbage"}, {"name": "Helen", "purchase": "HOW DO I REFERENCE THIS?"}]}';
var string = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(string['customers'][1]['purchase']);
```

and if you need to find "Helen" it would be something like this (with valid JSON):

```
var string = '{"employees": [{"name": "david", "car": "audi"}, {"name": "jimmy", "car": "VW"}], "customers": [{"name": "philip", "purchase": "cabbage"}, {"name": "Helen", "purchase": "HOW DO I REFERENCE THIS?"}]}';
var string = JSON.parse(string);
for (var i=0 ; i < string['customers'].length ; i++) {
    if (string['customers'][i]["name"] == "Helen") {
        var result = string['customers'][i]['purchase'];
    }
}
console.log(result);
```